# bar chart d3 circles under the bars

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I need to put circles under each column of my bar graph like this:

[image]

I have managed to make the ends of the bars of each one round, but I don't know how I can place each circle under each bar

This would be my code

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3
  .select("#my_chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Parse the Data
var data = [{
    group: "0",
    Nitrogen: "10"
  },
  {
    group: "1",
    Nitrogen: "30"
  },
  {
    group: "2",
    Nitrogen: "50"
  },
];
data.columns = ["group", "Nitrogen"];

// List of subgroups = header of the csv files = soil condition here
var subgroups = data.columns.slice(1);
console.log(data);
// List of groups = species here = value of the first column called group -> I show them on the X axis
var groups = d3
  .map(data, function(d) {
    return d.group;
  })
  .keys();

// Add X axis
var x = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(groups)
  .range([0, width])
  .padding([0.2]);
svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
  .attr("font-size", "0.9rem")
  .attr("font-weight", "400")
  .attr("color", "lightgray");

// Add Y axis
var y = d3
  .scaleLinear(25)
  .domain([0, 75])
  .range([height, 0])

;

svg
  .append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  .attr("font-size", "0.9rem")
  .attr("font-weight", "400")
  .attr("color", "lightgray")
  .attr("style", "transform: translate(0px, -12px);");

// Another scale for subgroup position?
var xSubgroup = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(subgroups)
  .range([0, x.bandwidth()])
  .padding([0.05]);

// color palette = one color per subgroup
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(subgroups).range(["#93B6F8"]);

// gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10);
}

// add the Y gridlines
svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_gridlines()
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat(""));

// Show the bars
svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  // Enter in data = loop group per group
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.group) + ",0)";
  })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return subgroups.map(function(key) {
      return {
        key: key,
        value: d[key]
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr(
    "style",
    "padding-bottom: 8px; transform: translate(0px, -6px);"
  )
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xSubgroup(d.key);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("width", xSubgroup.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.key);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_chart"></div>
```

and I show it this way:

[image]

And I would also like if it is not too much trouble, someone explains to me how to make the bars have a maximum width

Comment: What do you mean by "have a maximum width"? Make the size of the chart dependent on the number of bars? Or have a lot of whitespace?

Comment: Also, I find your code hard to understand. Do you have subgroups? Because you mention them in your code, but none of the images show multiple bar charts. Does the circle eat into the height of the bar or is it an extension? So should the circle be below y=0 or above it? You intentionally raise your y-axis by 12px. Why? Should that stay there?

Comment: I have copied the code that I have from an example of -graph-gallery.com, and well what I wanted to refer to is that the bars have a fixed width, although that is not really that important, I would like to know how to add the circles below the graphics

Comment: All right, mind if I answer your question using [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4) instead?

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following. I've taken the code from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4), kept it into the same structure, but reduced the bar height a bit and added circles on the bottom:

```js
var dataString = `salesperson,sales
Bob,33
Robin,12
Anne,41
Mark,16
Joe,59
Eve,38
Karen,21
Kirsty,25
Chris,30
Lisa,47
Tom,5
Stacy,20
Charles,13
Mary,29`;

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.5);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = d3.csvParse(dataString);

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.sales = +d.sales;
});

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.salesperson;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.sales;
})]);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
var barGroup = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  // Not rect, but g, we create one group per rect+circle combination
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar");

barGroup
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.salesperson);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.sales);
  })
  .attr("rx", 5) // Some rounded corners
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    // Subtract a little bit of height,
    // because we need to draw the circles underneath
    // return height - y(d.sales);
    return height - x.bandwidth() - y(d.sales);
  });

var circlePadding = 4; //pixels
barGroup
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.salesperson) + x.bandwidth() / 2;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return height - x.bandwidth() / 2;
  })
  .attr("r", x.bandwidth() / 2 - circlePadding);

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are the best, my respects